# Conflicting error message while programming in C over Debian WSL in VSCode

Tags: c, gcc, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to read the stats of a file and write them into a struct I have.

My code for this is the following

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

...

int bs_get_stat(const char* path, BsStat* result, int output_fd) {
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat(path, &statbuf) < 0) {
        perror("stat");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "not a regular file");
        return -1;
    }

    result->mode = statbuf.st_mode;
    result->owner = statbuf.st_uid;
    result->group = statbuf.st_gid;
    result->size = statbuf.st_size;
    result->atime.tv_sec = statbuf.st_atim.tv_sec;
    result->atime.tv_usec = statbuf.st_atim.tv_nsec / 1000;
    result->mtime.tv_sec = statbuf.st_mtim.tv_sec;
    result->mtime.tv_usec = statbuf.st_mtim.tv_nsec / 1000;

    return 0;
}
```

However VSCode tells me, that there is an error with st_atim and st_mtim and `struct "stat" has no field "st_atim"`

But when compiling all of it with gcc, it works fine.

If I now switch it up and write what VSCode tells me is correct the four lines look like this

```c
result->atime.tv_sec = statbuf.st_atime;
result->atime.tv_usec = statbuf.st_atimensec / 1000;
result->mtime.tv_sec = statbuf.st_mtime;
result->mtime.tv_usec = statbuf.st_mtimensec / 1000;
```

But this is now conflicting when compiling with gcc, which says

```
api/api.c: In function ‘bs_get_stat’:
api/api.c:101:44: error: request for member ‘tv_sec’ in something not a structure or union
     result->atime.tv_sec = statbuf.st_atime.tv_sec;
                                            ^
api/api.c:102:45: error: request for member ‘tv_nsec’ in something not a structure or union
     result->atime.tv_usec = statbuf.st_atime.tv_nsec / 1000;
                                             ^
api/api.c:103:44: error: request for member ‘tv_sec’ in something not a structure or union
     result->mtime.tv_sec = statbuf.st_mtime.tv_sec;
                                            ^
api/api.c:104:45: error: request for member ‘tv_nsec’ in something not a structure or union
     result->mtime.tv_usec = statbuf.st_mtime.tv_nsec / 1000;
```

So now I'm obviously very confused on why this is happening and don't know how to make VSCode "believe" that gcc is correct.
The thing that makes this more confusing is, that when Ctrl clicking on st_atimensec or so, it opens up the file `usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h`, where it has the according to VSCode correct fields.

Is there something I'm missing here?

**Edit:** Keep in mind that the now added includes are not all for the one function.
The function is part of a bigger file, where the other function need some of those.

Comment: You're not showing your `#include`s. Where exactly do you get `stat` from?

Comment: @tripleee Ah right, I forgot to copy those to the snippet.
I've now added them to the snippet